# view sections cause problems if not rendered in layout

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor, razorengine

I'm converting an **MVC aspx** content place holder -> master page to an **MVC razor** section -> layout.

In the past when my aspx view came to something like this:

```
<asp:Content ID="HelpContent" ContentPlaceHolderID="HelpLink" runat="server">
    <a href="../../Support" target="HPhelp" title="Open GideonSoft Help">Help</a>
</asp:Content>
```

And the master page didn't have a corresponding HelpContent place holder (perhaps because a user was not authenticated) everything rendered fine (with no HelpContent section).

Now when I have a razor section defined that does not have a corresponding @RenderSection in the layout, I get this error:

> The following sections have been defined but have not been rendered
>   for the layout page "~/Views/Shared/New.cshtml": "HelpLink".

Do I need to redesign this?

Is there a way I can have the view's HelpLink section render optionally if the layout gives it the green light?

**EDIT:**

I think there's some confusion, so let me re-summarize:

The layout logic looks like this:

```
if (User.IsLoggedIn) {
   @RenderSection( "HelpLinks", false);
}
```

But then the user isn't logged in, it doesn't render, and then .NET throws an exception because the layout doesn't know what to do with the section.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a section is declared in a razor view it has to be rendered in the layout.

I found this in Freeman's Pro ASP.NET MVC 5 book.

Seems like a bad design to me.

Answer (score 1):

You can indicate that the section is optional by passing `false` as the second argument:

> @RenderSection("HelpLink", false);

**Edit**:  In the case of control flow logic for rendering, you can use .NET in the razor view (like this c# example):

```
@if(IsSectionDefined("HelpLink"))
{
   @RenderSection("HelpLink", false);
}
```

Or, if you want to base rendering on whether the user is logged in, you could replace the if logic in the above sample with your security check.

**Edit 2**:

Make sure you have defined the section:

```
@section HelpLink {
   //This needs to be defined in any view that uses the layout with the @RenderSection.  It can be empty.
}
```

Alternatively, you can add the check to see if the section exists and only define the @section in the required view:

> if (IsSectionDefined("HelpLink") && User.IsLoggedIn) {
>
> @RenderSection( "HelpLinks", false);
>
> }

Comment: Thanks, but the problem the view specifies it, but it isn't called by the layout (because user lacks credentials). Unless there is a way to set it optional in the view?

Comment: responding to your updated answer: If the authentication logic determines NOT to render it, then I get an exception because there is a section that is not rendered. Hope that makes sense.